# Compiling Signtool.exe with Mono

Tags: .net, linux, mono, signing

I have tried to run Signtool.exe using wine to no avail. It aborts with the following Error Message, as I cant seem to figure out the exact cause for this I have tried running it using Mono

```
xvfb-run wine signtool.exe sign /debug /f [path to certificate] /fd SHA256 [path to file]    
        SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
        Error information: "Error: Store::ImportCertObject() failed." (-2146893823/0x80090001)
```

Trying to simply run the .exe with mono only returns

```
Cannot open assembly 'signtool.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

I have attempted to compile signtool.exe myself from the source code published in the [.NET Sourcecode](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.DotNet.SignTool/). This lead to the following Error

```
msbuild Microsoft.DotNetSignTool.csproject /t:build /restore
   "[path]/dotNetSigntool/Microsoft.DotNetSignTool.csproject" (Standardziel) (1) -> 
   /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2938,7): error MSB4057: 
   Das Ziel "CreateManifestResourceNames" ist im Projekt nicht vorhanden. [[path]/dotNetSigntool/Microsoft.DotNetSignTool.csproject]
```

(sorry for the german error message; translation: The Target "CreateManifestResourceNames" does not exist in the Project)

Therefor I was wondering what I was missing and how I could fix it.

Using alternative signingtools is probably no option aswell, as all I have found so far only sign .exe/.ps files and the project I am working on is supposed to sign the vba macro of an office file.

Comment: Have you considered https://linux.die.net/man/3/pkcs7_sign

Comment: @stark Sadly other Signtools wont help much as the MSOffice files are archives and only the VBA Project(which is inside of that archive) needs a signature. Also that Signature is a specific Microsoft Format, which I havent quite figured out yet. Thanks for the input tho!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/signtool/#dependencies-body-tab Someone already compiled the code and ship a NuGet package.